# Using Jastor to translate JSON/NSDictionary to Typed Swift classes

Tags: objective-c, class, swift, jastor

I'm going through [Jastor](https://github.com/elado/jastor)'s documentation:

There's an Objective-C implementation for [returning arrays](https://github.com/elado/jastor#arrays):

```
+ (Class)categories_class {
    return [ProductCategory class];
}
```

This is my attempt at converting it to Swift, however it ends up not returning anything so I don't think it's implemented correctly:

```
#<_TtC4TestApp4Room: id = (null) {
    resultCount = 50; // 50 is returning fine
    results =     ( // results is not
    );
}>
```

**NSDictionary response:**

```
{
  "resultCount" : 50,
  "results" : [
    {
      "collectionExplicitness" : "notExplicit",
      "discCount" : 1,
      "artworkUrl60" : "http:\/\/a4.mzstatic.com\/us\/r30\/Features\/2a\/b7\/da\/dj.kkirmfzh.60x60-50.jpg",
      "collectionCensoredName" : "Changes in Latitudes, Changes in Attitudes (Ultmate Master Disk  Gold CD  Reissue)"
    }
   ]
}
```

**Music.swift** *(not quite sure how to implement the `results_class()` method)*

```
class Music : Jastor {

    var resultCount: NSNumber = 0
    var results: NSArray = []

    class func results_class() -> AnyClass {
        return Author.self
    }
}
```

**Author.swift**

```
class Author {

    var collectionExplicitness: NSString = ""
    var discCount: NSNumber = 0
    var artworkUrl60: NSString = ""
    var collectionCensoredName: NSString = ""

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the following syntax (adapted to your example):

```
static let results_class = Author.self
```

and everything works for me.

Other differences that may or may not have an effect:

- I'm using `Int` instead of `NSNumber` and `String` instead of `NSString` (except for arrays).
- I'm using implicitly wrapped optionals rather than assigning a default value to each field

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I had to change `Int` to `NSNumber` to get everything to work.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach, albeit working, was causing memory leaks related to Jastor's init methods. After trying to fix them in many other ways, we had to revert to having our Jastor subclasses in Objective-C (but with Swift subclasses where needed) to get rid of them :/